# Ruby not running print before end of program

Tags: ruby

My ruby code is not working the way I would expect. My expectation is that it will print *"What is your name?"* before taking the user input. As seen in my output though, this is not the case. I am hoping that I could get an explanation as to why this is happening, and then a solution where I get my expected results.

**playground.rb**

```rb
puts "What is your name? "

name = gets.chomp

puts "Hello " + name + ". How are you?"
```

**output**

```sh
$ ruby playground.rb
asd
what is your name?
Hello asd. How are you?
```

Comment: There are a few things less than ideal with this question.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem, have voted to close.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this on MSYS2 in Windows and find a solution, but I'm not sure if that is what you need.  Please tell us what operating system you are using, what version of Ruby (and where it came from), what shell you are using (i.e. bash, Windows Command Prompt), and what terminal program (i.e. MinTTY, standard Windows text window).

Answer (score 1):

If the Ruby process takes a moment to start you can type in input prior to the prompt being displayed.

This is precisely the same behaviour you'll get with *any* interactive program in the shell. You're free to type input at any time, for any reason, with any program, regardless of if or when that input is used. This is not unique to Ruby.

By typing in advance you're basically front-loading the input buffer.